# Induced map between homology $H_n(S^n) \to H_n(\mathbb RP^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $q:S^n\to \mathbb RP^n$ be the map that glues the antipodal points of $S^n$, I have a feeling that the induced map between homology $H_n(S^n) \to H_n(\mathbb RP^n)$ is the multiplication-by-2 map but I don't know how to verify it. For simplicity lets assure the coefficient group is $\mathbb Z_2$so that both groups are $\mathbb Z_2$, but I think this (the map is the multiplication-by-2) is true in more general coefficients.

Comment: Consider a cell decomposition that makes $q$ cellular and the corresponding map between cellular complexes.

Comment: For coefficients $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n) = 0$ if $n$ is even and $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Study the homology exact sequence of the cofiber sequence $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n\xrightarrow{p}S^n$ and determine the map $p_*:H_n\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow H_nS^n$. Use this to study the self-map $p\circ q:S^n\rightarrow S^n$.

Comment: If $p: E \to B$ is a finite-degree covering map (say degree $k$), then there is a map $\text{tr}_p: H_*(B) \to H_*(E)$ called the transfer, where you lift a cell downstairs to $k$ copies of that cell upstairs. The composite $\text{tr}_p p_*$ is multiplication by $k$ - you can check this by hand. And furthermore, if $B$ is a closed oriented manifold, $\text{tr}_p$ is an isomorphism on top degree classes; again you can check this by hand, as you are taking a fundamental class downstairs to a fundamental class upstairs. So you conclude.

Comment: With $n=2$ and integral homology we must have that $p^*:H_2(S^2)\rightarrow H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ is zero, but the comment about transfer would imply that $2$ from $H_2(S^2)$ to itself factors through $0$ so I feel like I am missing something simple here.