# Calculate the map on homology induced by the quotient map $S^ 3 → \Bbb R {\Bbb P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Calculate the map on homology induced by the quotient map $S^
> 3 → \Bbb R {\Bbb P}^3$

I understand the quotient map $q:S^3 → \Bbb R {\Bbb P}^3$ i.e. identifying antipodal points i.e. for $x \in S^3$ consider te corresponding $[x] \in \Bbb R {\Bbb P}^3$ then, $q(x)=q(-x)=[x] , \forall x \in S^3$ .

It is a 2-sheeted covering map and hence should give a degree 2 map and hence in the level of homology, it should behave like $n \mapsto 2n$ .But not quite clear to me.

I have visited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990107/induced-map-between-homology-h-nsn-to-h-n-mathbb-rpn)  but it has a few comments, I want to understand this concept and so if someone vance for help!can write a detailed answer about what is going on here and how to compute it, it will gteatly help my cause ( also to understand similar problems) . Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general the canonical quotient map $q:S^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n$ is the attaching map for the top cell of $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$. This means that there is a cofibration sequence

$$S^n\xrightarrow{q}\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$$

and in particular a long exact sequence in homology

$$\dots\rightarrow H_{k+1}\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}\rightarrow H_kS^n\xrightarrow{q_*}H_k\mathbb{R}P^n \rightarrow H_k\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}\rightarrow H_{k-1}S^n\rightarrow\dots$$

If we put a CW structure on $S^n$ with two cells in each dimension $0\leq r\leq n$ then these cells are permuted by the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action of the antipodal map. Hence the structure descends to give a CW structure of the quotient $\mathbb{R}P^n$
which has one cell in each dimension $0\leq r\leq n$.

Then in $S^n$, the boundary orientation of the two $r$-cells agrees if $r$ is even, and is opposite in the case that $r$ is odd. This means that the cellular complex $C_*S^n$ (whose homology computes $H_*S^n$) is actually exact in degrees $\neq 0,n$. On the other hand, it means that in $C_*\mathbb{R}P^m$, where the cells in each dimension are identified, the differentials are either trivial (when the orientations are opposite), or multiplication by $2$ (when the orientations agree). Hence we compute

$$\tilde H_k\mathbb{R}P^{2r}\cong\begin{cases}0&k\leq 2r\:\text{even}\\\mathbb{Z}_2&k\leq 2r\:\text{odd}\end{cases}$$

and

$$\tilde H_k\mathbb{R}P^{2r+1}\cong\begin{cases}0&k< 2r+1\:\text{even}\\\mathbb{Z}_2&k<2r+1\;\text{odd}\\
\mathbb{Z}&k=2r+1\end{cases}$$

This gives us that whenever $n=2r+1$ is odd we have an exact sequence

$$H_{2r+2}\mathbb{R}P^{2r+2}\rightarrow H_{2r+1}S^{2r+1}\xrightarrow{q_*} H_{2r+1}\mathbb{R}P^{2r+1}3\rightarrow H_{2r+1}\mathbb{R}P^{2r+2}\rightarrow H_{2r}S^{2r+1}$$

which is exactly

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{q_*}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow 0.$$

Hence $q_*:H_{2r+1}S^{2r+1}\rightarrow H_{2r+1}\mathbb{R}P^{2r+1}$ is multiplication by $2$. In particular this holds for the odd integer $n=3$.

Comment: Is the homology of projective space usually calculated in a different way then computing its cellular homology? If so, isn't it somewhat circular to use the homology of projective space when it requires calculating the degree of the map in question?

Comment: @ConnorMalin If you calculate the homology of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ using knowledge of the degree then the argument would be circular. The reason I described the cellular calculation was to avoid such circularity. Note that the cellular calculation uses very much the fact that the quotient is a 2-sheeted covering map, but it does not invoke any abstract properties of such maps to reach its conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Along with Tyrone's comprehensive computation, you can also see it at the level of cell-structures since it's just a finite cover. The argument I give here is somewhat along the lines of arguing using the transfer map for finite covers. (All of the chain and homology groups are cellular.)

Choose a CW structure for $S^n$ which has two cells in each dimension $0\leq i \leq n$ and so that the antipodal map $a\colon S^n \to S^n$ is cellular. Then there is an induced cell-structure on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with one cell in each dimension $0\leq i \leq n$ and so that the quotient map $q\colon S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ is cellular.

Now, $H_k(S^n)$ is only non-zero in two degrees: $0$ and $n$.

In $H_0$, $q$ induces an isomorphism since both spaces are connected.

For $H_n(S^n)$, given the $2$-cell $\varphi_+\colon D^n \to S^n$ representing the upper hemisphere, then the sum $\varphi_+ + a_*(\varphi_+) \in C_n(S^n)$ is a cycle, and generates $H_n$. If $\varphi_P\in C_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ is the elementary chain given by the unique $2$-cell, then 
$$q_*(\varphi_+ + a_*(\varphi_+)) = 2 \varphi_P$$

Since $\varphi_P$ is the only $n$-cell, it and its multiples are the only candidates for elements of $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)$, but in fact it is a cycle iff the antipodal map on $S^{n-1}$ reverses orientation (otherwise its boundary is $2$ times the generator of $C_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}P^n)$), iff $n$ is odd. Therefore if $n$ is even then $H_n(q)\colon \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is the $0$ map, and if $n$ is odd then $[\varphi_P]$ generates $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and  $H_n(q)\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by $2$.